# Проблема с отладкой: No local changes, not deploying APK Could not identify launch

Tags: android

Студия видит внешнее устройство, даже она смогла загрузить туда приложение сама,
но отладчик выдает такую ошибку:

> No local changes, not deploying APK Could not identify launch
>   activity: Default Activity not found Error while Launching activity

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

У вас не указан `Intent Filter`

```
 <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

Примерно так, в манифесте к активити